# Selecting items from the dialog box in Android activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am implementing a dialog box inside the activity in android

It has list of camera names and checkbox to select them.

I need support to implement the below scenario:

1. when we start activity, there is restriction that user can select max 4 names
2. So when we open the dialog box for first time,  user can select 1 or more upto maximum 4 camera names.
3. If user select all 4, then rest of the rows must be dimmed , to avoid user from selecting any more.
4. If user select e.g 2, next time he opens the dialog box again, the selected rows must be dimmed/disabled, so that user cannot select them again.
5. and then he can select maximum 2 more camera from the dialog list ( total making it 4)

So the point is..there is restriction to select 4 camera only.

User can select 1 time, maybe 2 camera and come back and select 2 more.

every time he open the dialog box, previous selected camera rows must be disabled, so that user cannot select again

Kindly let me know how to achieve point 3, 4 and 5 .

Please find the code for my dialog box:

```
 String[] arStrCam = se.split(",");
 for (int i = 0; i < arStrCam.length; i++)
            {
                checkedItems[i] = false;
            }

            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.Channel);
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(arStrCam, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
                {
  }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    mStrCamList = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (checkedItems[i] == true)
                        {
                                mStrCamList += arStrCam[i]+",";
                           }
                    }
                   if (mStrCamList.equals("") == true)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                       showToast(R.string.Select_one_or_more_channel);                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      Toast.makeText(FavoriteDeviceListActivity.this, mStrCamList, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        addDisplay(mCamName, mCamModel, mStrCamList);                     
                    }                    
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();                    
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
```

Comment: What do you call a dialog box? is it a dialog that show on top of the activity or are you talking about a combobox?

Comment: use DialogFragment and let your checkbox share the same OnCheckChangedListener and do the counting / save the selected ones (as sharedPreferences for example)

Comment: @LaryCiminera it is a dialog box that show on top of activity